# Formattable based on multiple columns

Tags: r, format, formattable

I am using the package `formattable` to generate a formatted table. I found a nice resource [Formatting tables in R](http://www.r-bloggers.com/formatting-table-output-in-r/). But here the example of arrow formatting is based only on the specific column.

My requirement is: Say I have from different cities, column A and B, where A has factors with two levels 'Number of Trees' and 'Pollution', while B is the percentage change of these YoY. So I want to format the Column B with a positive green arrow if there has an increase for Column A values being 'Number of Trees' (since it is positive) and red if there is a decrease while for pollution the other way round.

So taking the example (credit: **Markus Gesmann**) from the link itself, say just for IBM even if the change is <0, I want to show a positive green arrow against it.

```
library(formattable)
DF <- data.frame(Ticker=c("", "", "", "IBM", "AAPL", "MSFT"),
             Name=c("Dow Jones", "S&P 500", "Technology", 
                    "IBM", "Apple", "Microsoft"),
             Value=accounting(c(15988.08, 1880.33, NA, 
                                130.00, 97.05, 50.99)),
             Change=percent(c(-0.0239, -0.0216, 0.021, 
                              -0.0219, -0.0248, -0.0399)))
DF
##   Ticker       Name     Value Change
## 1         Dow Jones 15,988.08 -2.39%
## 2           S&P 500  1,880.33 -2.16%
## 3        Technology        NA  2.10%
## 4    IBM        IBM    130.00 -2.19%
## 5   AAPL      Apple     97.05 -2.48%
## 6   MSFT  Microsoft     50.99 -3.99%
formattable(DF, list(
  Name=formatter(
    "span",
    style = x ~ ifelse(x == "Technology", 
                       style(font.weight = "bold"), NA)),
  Value = color_tile("white", "orange"),
  Change = formatter(
    "span",
    style = x ~ style(color = ifelse(x < 0 , "red", "green")),
    x ~ icontext(ifelse(x < 0, "arrow-down", "arrow-up"), x)))
)
```

Comment: Some sample data would be helpful, and some sample code that you have tried that uses this sample data but doesn't work the way you expect would be even more helpful.

Comment: Hi vielmetti, I have added an example and the code, unfortunately I do not know what is the alternate code to achieve this that is not working, hence not adding. Thanks

Comment: Thanks Anurag H - can you adjust your sample code so that it includes data that reflects your condition - e.g. so that it has trees and pollution instead of stock ticker information?

Comment: vielmetti, actually the data type was just an example, I am working on a client data set which has similar application but unfortunately not sharable, but the stock data is closely similar, so I would want to define the color on "Change" column such that for all values other than IBM, I have green positive for increase else red, while for IBM green for decrease and red for increase. Sorry for the inconvenience, hope this assists

Comment: I find the example adequate to illustrate the problem (but am stumped).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Based on the doc at `?formatter`:

```
formattable(DF, list(
  Name=formatter(
    "span",
    style = x ~ ifelse(x == "Technology", 
                       style(font.weight = "bold"), NA)),
  Value = color_tile("white", "orange"),
  Change = formatter(
    "span",
    style = ~ style(color = ifelse(Change < 0 & Ticker != "IBM", "red", "green")),
    ~ icontext(ifelse(Change < 0 & Name != "IBM", "arrow-down", "arrow-up"), Change)))
)
```

Apparently, the `x ~` formula style restricts you to use the only the variable itself on the right-hand side. You have to switch to `~` and then write the column name explicitly on the right-hand side (instead of as `x`).

Comment: Pure elegance! Well Done Frank