# Conditional Formatting using Formattable R

Tags: r, html-table, formattable

I have a dataframe that looks like:

```
   from   to  value sourceID targetID clustid
1  1400 1413 0.6846  3055586  3060697       1
2   323  661 0.5550  1596205   724084       1
3   323 1411 0.6817   724084  3060607       1
4  1413 1411 0.6729  3060697  3060607       1
5  1498 1411 0.6381  3111960  3060607       1
6  1478 1415 0.7423  3062164  3099199       2
7  1478 1414 0.7423  3099199  3062163       2
8  1415 1462 0.7078  3090708  3062164       2
9  1415 1463 0.7078  3062164  3090709       2
10 1462 1404 0.7078  3090708  3058341       2
11 1418  278 0.5048  3064885   612944       3
12 1418  851 0.5595  3064885  1919812       3
13 1418 1355 0.5932  3064885  3018082       3
14 1417  278 0.5048  3064884   612944       3
15 1417  851 0.5595  3064884  1919812       3
16  862  851 0.6109  1935866  1919812       3
17  525 1632 0.6565  1365467  3458397       4
18  525  506 0.6031  1365467  1312582       4
19 1445  526 0.5288  3083388  1365468       4
20 1445 1632 0.5077  3083388  3458397       4
21 1445 1271 0.7222  3083388  2933726       4
22  526 1270 0.5121  1365468  2933725       4
23  611  582 0.6245  1477137  1519842       5
24  611  567 0.6245  1519842  1450552       5
25  611  579 0.5230  1519842  1469099       5
26  582  568 0.6381  1477137  1450553       5
27  567  616 0.7150  1450552  1528881       5
28  120  121 0.7719   370873   370871       6
29  120  438 0.6054   370871  1145838       6
30  120  166 0.5995   370871   431814       6
31  121  125 0.6452   370873   374920       6
32  121  439 0.6054   370873  1145839       6
```

I am using `formattable` to create an html output.

I want to colour the background depending on the value of `clustid`

I first tried:

```
formattable(df, 
            list(area(col = names(df)) ~ formatter("span",
                                                  style = ~ style(color = ifelse(df$clustid %% 2, "red", "grey")))))
```

But this changes only the colour of the text itself.

From the limited documentation and this question [Formattable based on multiple columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37821493/formattable-based-on-multiple-columns) and some other resources I managed to cobble together the following:

```
formattable(df,  list(area(col = names(df)) ~ formatter("span", style = ~ style("background-color" = ifelse(df$clustid %% 2, "white", "grey")))))
```

This produces:

[image]

Rather than highlighting the background of the words themselves, I want to highlight the entire row itself.

I would rather highlight the entire row as opposed to just an individual cell. How can this be done?

Many thanks :)

---

Edit: Originally included the following on `color-tile` however it appears this is for a gradient across rows for a specific column, so as such is not applicable in this case.

---

[This is Incorrect but left as to not distrub the original question]

```
formattable(df, list(area(1:5) ~ color_tile("transparent", "lightgray")
```

But of course, there is no corresponding image included to show the output, or even the test data itself...

When I try to implement this with my conditional statements I get the following error:

```
formattable(df,  list(area(col = names(df)) ~ color_tile(ifelse(df$clustid %% 2, "white", "grey"))))

Error in grepl(if (alpha) "^#([0-9a-fA-F]{2}){3,4}$" else "^#([0-9a-fA-F]{2}){3}$",  : 
  argument "max.color" is missing, with no default
```